# Как создать элементы с разными атрибутами?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Мне нужно создать n `div` элементов внутри `body`. Все `div` элементы должны иметь один общий класс, а также каждый должен иметь свой личный атрибут.

Пока что получился такой код:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const divEl = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(divEl).setAttribute('class', 'div');
}
```

Как мне дополнительно к элементу добавить свой атрибут? Ибо сейчас они создаются лишь с классом "div", а мне нужны еще атрибуты.

Есть идея после создания получить все элементы и к каждому заново обращаться, но, думаю, это не лучший вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать массив конфигураций для `div`-ов и отталкиваться от него:

```
const divConfigs = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2, pid: 20 },
  { tid: 300 }
];

for (let divConfig of divConfigs) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class", "div");

  for (let attribute in divConfig) {
    div.setAttribute(attribute, divConfig[attribute]);
  }

  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Конфигурация представляет собой объект, в котором ключами являются названия атрибутов, а значениями - значения соответствующих атрибутов

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то ты сначала создаешь все нужные объекты, а потом уже каждому из них присваиваешь атрибуты?

Comment: @Gelloiss сначала в `divConfigs` описывается какому `div`-у нужно будет добавить какие атрибуты, а затем в цикле создаются `div`-ы и им проставляются соответствующие атрибуты

Comment: Я понял. Поиграюсь еще, чтобы окончательно осознать. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

не вижу смысла искать какой-то мудреный способ. вот этот читабельный и обычный:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const divEl = document.createElement('div');
    divEl.classList.add('div');
    divEl.setAttribute('myAttr', 'value');
    document.body.appendChild(divEl);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, похоже ты ответил на мой вопрос. Я просто только изучаю JS и не сразу понимаю как он работает.

Comment: @Gelloiss если нужно было каждому `div`-у добавить один и тот же атрибут с одним и тем же значением (как в данном ответе), то как это соотносится с текстом "свой личный атрибут" из вопроса?

Comment: @Regent в моем случае "свой личный атрибут" будет зависеть от счетчика цикла (i). Ну или браться из массивов атрибутов.